# collectMultidex task looking in wrong place for manifest.xml

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-multidex

When trying to enable multi-dexing for an application over 65K, following the guidelines specified by the android developer page [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

While in my application build.gradle I specify:

```
android.applicationVariants.all{
    variant -> variant.outputs.each {
        output ->
            output.processResources.manifestFile = file('AndroidManifest.xml')
            output.processManifest.enabled=false
    }
}
```

Upon running build I receive this error,

> Error: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':myapp:collectDebugMultiDexComponents'.
>
> File 'C:\Android Projects\myappapp\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.

Open to any suggestions or advice to properly direct multi dex task to actual AndroidManifest.xml path. When removing the library that causes the application to cross the 64k limit and removing multidexing the application builds fine.